# Check unique values in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to prevent copy pasting data in excel if the data is not unique. Im using the following macro.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
Dim AffectedCells As Range
Dim Cell As Range

Set AffectedCells = Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("A:A"))
If Not AffectedCells Is Nothing Then 
  For Each Cell In AffectedCells
    If CountIf(Range("A:A"),A1) >2 Then
      MsgBox "The data """ & Cell.Value & """ inserted in " & Cell.Address & " in column A is duplicste. We undo!", vbCritical Application.Undo 'undo insert     
      Exit Sub 
    End If 
  Next Cell 
End If
End Sub
```

It is still allowing the data to be pasted.

I tried letting excel not save itself if the value is duplicate but it is still saving.

```
    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean) 
    Dim rngCell As Range 
    Dim lngLstRow As Long lngLstRow = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count 
      For Each rngCell In Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & lngLstRow) 
     If CountIf(Range("A:A"),A1) > 2 Then 
      MsgBox "Please enter unique value " & rngCell.Address 
      rngCell.Select
       End If 
      Next   
       End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't `CountIf` be >=2?

Comment: Its not working anyway. I also tried not letting the excel save the sheet if value is duplicate but it is still saving anyway.

Comment: Actually want a workaround for the issue that excel is ignoring data validation rule when copy pasting the data

Comment: Have you tried putting `Application.Undo` on it's own line?

Comment: I have updated the question with my second approach. Plz look at that also.

Comment: Why are you using `A1` instead of `rng.Value` or `rngCell.Value`, and `> 2` instead of `> 1`?

Comment: Tried that as well but it is not working

Comment: You have to force the user to change the value, e.g. using `Application.InputBox` instead of `MsgBox`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 i simply want an error message to get displayed when user pastes a data which has duplicate values.

Comment: Problem that you have is that you are doing this in `Worksheet_Change` method. If someone paste the data, you will display the msg but your data still remains the same. You have to use `Worksheet_SelectionChange` in conjunction with `Worksheet_Change`. Do the same checks in `Worksheet_SelectionChange` method to ensure you are in the correct range. Then save the values in an array. Now if someone paste's a value, display the msg in `Worksheet_Change` and then reset the values in the range

Comment: I fixed the issue on my own. My code is working in workbook before save function.

Comment: Have voted to close as OP has fixed the issue and "this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers."